# Trigonometric Idntities under the condition $A+B+C=π$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$A+B+C=\pi$$, prove that 
$$\cos\frac{A}{2}+\cos\frac{B}{2}+\cos\frac{C}{2}=4\cos\frac{\pi-A}{4}.\cos\frac{\pi-B}{4}.\cos\frac{\pi-C}{4}$$.

My solution:
Here

$$A+B+C=\pi$$
$$A+B=\pi-C$$
Taking 'sine' on both sides gives
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin C$$.
Now,
$$L.H.S=\cos\frac{A}{2}+\cos\frac{B}{2}+\cos\frac{C}{2}$$

Which formula should I use now? Please help.

Comment: Any particular reason for taking sine

Comment: @Archis, I haven't any particular reason for taking sine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the trig identity: $\cos x+\cos y=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$,

Now, consider $$LHS=\cos\frac A2+\cos\frac{B}{2}+\cos \frac C2$$
$$=\left(\cos\frac A2+\cos\frac{B}{2}\right)+\cos \frac C2$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{\frac{A}{2}+\frac B2}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\frac{A}{2}-\frac B2}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi-A-B}{2}\right)$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{4}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

$$=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{4}\right)+\sin 2\left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{4}\right)+2\sin \left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\cos \left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{4}\right)+2\sin \left(\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\cos \left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{4}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{A+B}{4}\right)\right]$$
$$=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)\left[2\cos\left(\frac{\frac{A-B}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{A+B}{4}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\frac{A-B}{4}-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{A+B}{4}}{2}\right)\right]$$
$$=4\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi-B}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi-A}{4}\right)\right]$$
$$=4\cos\left(\frac{\pi-A}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi-B}{4}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi-C}{4}\right)=RHS$$

Comment: @ Harish, could you please tell me that your book 'Advance Geometry' is for which level(or grade/class)?

Comment: Thanks for asking. This book is not actually class specific, however anyone, interested in Geometry usually at higher level, can  refer to it as it mainly deals with the detailed study of solid angle in 3-D & some other articles in 2-D Geometry.

Comment: is it available for sale in India only or overseas, too?

Comment: Yes, it is available in India & overseas by online distributors like Amazon, Flipkart etc.

Comment: What is its MRP then?

Comment: Its MRP may vary depending on the distributor. You can get all details about book's  MRPs through the link: https://notionpress.com/read/advanced-geometry-1294526

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\textrm{LHS}&= \left(\cos\frac{A}{2}+\cos\frac{B}{2}\right)+\cos\frac{C}{2}\\ &= 2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\cos\frac{A-B}{4} + \sin\frac{A+B}{2}\\ &= 2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\cos\frac{A-B}{4} +2\sin\frac{A+B}{4}\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\\&=2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\left[\cos\frac{A-B}{4} + \sin\frac{A+B}{4}\right]\\ &= 2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\left[\cos\frac{A-B}{4} +\cos\left({\pi\over 2} - \frac{A+B}{4}\right)\right]\\ &= 2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\left[2\cos\frac{\frac{A-B}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{A+B}{4}}{2}\cos\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{A+B}{4}- \frac{A-B}{4}}{2}\right]\\ &=2\cos\frac{A+B}{4}\left[2 \cos\frac{\pi -B}{4}\cdot \cos\frac{\pi-A}{4}\right] \\ &= 4\cos\frac{\pi -A}{4}\cdot \cos\frac{\pi -B}{4}\cdot \cos\frac{\pi-C}{4}  \\ &= \rm {RHS}\;.\end{align}

Comment: Why the downote?

Comment: oops! it seems you have literally copied this answer.

Comment: @Bhaskara-III: WTF!

Comment: @Bhaskara-III: BTW, whose answer have I copied from?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac{\pi-A}4=x$ etc. $\implies A=\pi-4x$

and $\sum4x=3\pi-\sum A=2\pi\iff x+y+z=\dfrac\pi2$

$$\cos\dfrac A2=\cdots=\sin2x$$

$$\sin2x+\sin2y+\sin2z=2\sin(x+y)\cos(x-y)+2\sin z\cos z$$

$$=2\sin(\pi/2-z)\cos(x-y)+2\cos z\sin\{\pi/2-(x+y)\}$$

$$=2\cos(z)\cos(x-y)+2\cos z\cos\{(x+y)\}$$

$$=2\cos(z)\{\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)\}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: which formula did you use in the second step as I haven't read about it till now and hence, did not understand...

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, Are you talking about $\sin2x+\sin2y,$ then see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: I  am asking about $$\sum4x=3\pi-\sum A$$

Comment: @Iaamuseruser, $$4x=\pi-A$$ right  $$4(x+y+z)=3\pi-(A+B+C)$$ and $A+B+C=\pi$